# How to rename many files using info from a separate .txt file?

Tags: scripts, rename

I believe this problem can be solved with a bash script, but I'm still a beginner so I need your help here.

I have many files (about 8 million!) with names such as `IR.AZR..SHE.D.2016.001.000000.SAC`. The file names follow this format:

```
IR.(stations name)..(component).D.(year).(day).000000.sac
```

They all need to be renamed to the following format:

```
(station name).IR.(component).(year).(day).(begin time).(endtime).sac
```

Note: `(day)` is in 365 format or maybe I should say it is in **Julian day** format.

The current file name, along with the additional information required for the new format, is stored in a plain text file:

[image: screenshot of file names with additional data needed for renaming]

In addition to the screenshot, here is a part from the file:

```
IR.AZR..SHE.D.2016.158.071819.SAC  2016 158  7 18 19 300        0.0000        8.2000
IR.AZR..SHE.D.2016.158.072153.SAC  2016 158  7 21 53 540        0.0000        8.2000
IR.AZR..SHE.D.2016.158.072251.SAC  2016 158  7 22 51  60        0.0000        8.1000
IR.AZR..SHE.D.2016.158.072315.SAC  2016 158  7 23 15 580        0.0000       16.3000
IR.AZR..SHE.D.2016.158.072340.SAC  2016 158  7 23 40 180        0.0000        8.2000
IR.AZR..SHE.D.2016.158.072421.SAC  2016 158  7 24 21 300        0.0000        8.1000
IR.AZR..SHE.D.2016.158.072445.SAC  2016 158  7 24 45 980        0.0000        8.2000
IR.AZR..SHE.D.2016.158.072518.SAC  2016 158  7 25 18  60        0.0000        7.3000
IR.AZR..SHE.D.2016.158.072541.SAC  2016 158  7 25 41 620        0.0000       32.9000
IR.AZR..SHE.D.2016.158.072647.SAC  2016 158  7 26 47 540        0.0000       16.4000
IR.AZR..SHE.D.2016.158.072712.SAC  2016 158  7 27 12 260        0.0000        8.1000
IR.AZR..SHE.D.2016.158.072736.SAC  2016 158  7 27 36 860        0.0000        8.2000
IR.AZR..SHE.D.2016.158.072753.SAC  2016 158  7 27 53 340        0.0000        8.2000
IR.AZR..SHE.D.2016.158.072809.SAC  2016 158  7 28  9 820        0.0000        8.1000
IR.AZR..SHE.D.2016.158.072904.SAC  2016 158  7 29  4 740        0.0000        8.2000
IR.AZR..SHE.D.2016.158.072921.SAC  2016 158  7 29 21 220        0.0000        8.2000
IR.AZR..SHE.D.2016.158.072954.SAC  2016 158  7 29 54  60        0.0000        8.2000
IR.AZR..SHE.D.2016.158.073035.SAC  2016 158  7 30 35 260        0.0000        8.1000
IR.AZR..SHE.D.2016.158.073059.SAC  2016 158  7 30 59 940        0.0000        8.2000
```

- The **first** column is a list of my files, with their current filenames.
- The **second** is column represents the `(year)`.
- The **third** is `(day)` in Julian Day format.
- The **eighth** and **ninth** column are `(begin time)` and `(end time)`, respectively.

In plain words the script should do the following:

> First list all files and then find the file inside this `.txt` file and the corresponding row and column and rename as I said above.

Comment: It's ok being a beginner! Please show how you tried to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you ask can be easily accomplished with a Perl one-liner:

```
perl -lane '@a=split/\./,$F[0]; rename "old/$F[0]","new/$a[1].IR.$a[3].$F[1].$F[2].$F[7].$F[8].sac"' input.txt
```

**However**, your new format naming scheme does not seem appropriate for your input files, since it will create duplicate names. E.g.:

```
IR.AZR..SHE.D.2016.158.071819.SAC  2016 158  7 18 19 300        0.0000        8.2000
IR.AZR..SHE.D.2016.158.072153.SAC  2016 158  7 21 53 540        0.0000        8.2000
```

will both translate to: `AZR.IR.SHE.2016.158.0.0000.8.2000.sac`. Obviously, there can be only one file with a given filename at any one time, and one of them will be lost.

Please account for duplicates, rethinking the output filename format. One possible alternative could be:

```
perl -lane '@a=split/\./,$F[0]; rename "old/$F[0]","new/$a[1].IR.$a[3].$F[1].$F[2].$a[7].$F[7].$F[8].sac"' input.txt
```

---

**Test run**

Initial file structure:

```
old:
IR.AZR..SHE.D.2016.158.071819.SAC
IR.AZR..SHE.D.2016.158.072153.SAC
IR.AZR..SHE.D.2016.158.072251.SAC
IR.AZR..SHE.D.2016.158.072315.SAC
IR.AZR..SHE.D.2016.158.072340.SAC
IR.AZR..SHE.D.2016.158.072421.SAC
IR.AZR..SHE.D.2016.158.072445.SAC
IR.AZR..SHE.D.2016.158.072518.SAC
IR.AZR..SHE.D.2016.158.072541.SAC
IR.AZR..SHE.D.2016.158.072647.SAC
IR.AZR..SHE.D.2016.158.072712.SAC
IR.AZR..SHE.D.2016.158.072736.SAC
IR.AZR..SHE.D.2016.158.072753.SAC
IR.AZR..SHE.D.2016.158.072809.SAC
IR.AZR..SHE.D.2016.158.072904.SAC
IR.AZR..SHE.D.2016.158.072921.SAC
IR.AZR..SHE.D.2016.158.072954.SAC
IR.AZR..SHE.D.2016.158.073035.SAC
IR.AZR..SHE.D.2016.158.073059.SAC

new:
```

Test run with the OP's original format:

```
old:

new:
AZR.IR.SHE.2016.158.0.0000.16.3000.sac
AZR.IR.SHE.2016.158.0.0000.16.4000.sac
AZR.IR.SHE.2016.158.0.0000.32.9000.sac
AZR.IR.SHE.2016.158.0.0000.7.3000.sac
AZR.IR.SHE.2016.158.0.0000.8.1000.sac
AZR.IR.SHE.2016.158.0.0000.8.2000.sac
```

Test run with the altered output format:

```
old:

new:
AZR.IR.SHE.2016.158.071819.0.0000.8.2000.sac
AZR.IR.SHE.2016.158.072153.0.0000.8.2000.sac
AZR.IR.SHE.2016.158.072251.0.0000.8.1000.sac
AZR.IR.SHE.2016.158.072315.0.0000.16.3000.sac
AZR.IR.SHE.2016.158.072340.0.0000.8.2000.sac
AZR.IR.SHE.2016.158.072421.0.0000.8.1000.sac
AZR.IR.SHE.2016.158.072445.0.0000.8.2000.sac
AZR.IR.SHE.2016.158.072518.0.0000.7.3000.sac
AZR.IR.SHE.2016.158.072541.0.0000.32.9000.sac
AZR.IR.SHE.2016.158.072647.0.0000.16.4000.sac
AZR.IR.SHE.2016.158.072712.0.0000.8.1000.sac
AZR.IR.SHE.2016.158.072736.0.0000.8.2000.sac
AZR.IR.SHE.2016.158.072753.0.0000.8.2000.sac
AZR.IR.SHE.2016.158.072809.0.0000.8.1000.sac
AZR.IR.SHE.2016.158.072904.0.0000.8.2000.sac
AZR.IR.SHE.2016.158.072921.0.0000.8.2000.sac
AZR.IR.SHE.2016.158.072954.0.0000.8.2000.sac
AZR.IR.SHE.2016.158.073035.0.0000.8.1000.sac
AZR.IR.SHE.2016.158.073059.0.0000.8.2000.sac
```

Answer (score 1):

### Pure Bash + [`mv(1)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/mv.1.html)

```sh
while read -r current year day d e f g begin end; do
  station="${current:3:3}" component="${current:8:3}"
  mv -T -- "$current" "${station}.IR.${component}.${year}.${day}.${begin}.${end}.sac"
done < file-name-data.txt
```

Although with 8 million files it will be quite slow to execute `mv` for each of them. Hence why I recommend the alternative below.

### Python 3

#### One-liner (no error handling)

```sh
python3 -c 'import sys, os, re; for m in map(re.compile(sys.argv[1]).match, sys.stdin): os.rename(m.group("current"), sys.argv[2].format_map(m.groupdict()))' '(?P<current>IR\.(?P<station>\S+?)\.\.(?P<component>\S+?)\.\S*)\s+(?P<year>\S+)\s+(?P<day>\S+)\s+(?:\S+\s+){4}(?P<begin>\S+)\s+(?P<end>\S+)' '{station}.IR.{component}.{year}.{day}.{begin}.{end}.sac' < file-name-data.txt
```

#### Full program (with error handling)

```python
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys, os, re

src_pattern = re.compile(
  r'(?P<current>IR\.(?P<station>\S+?)\.\.(?P<component>\S+?)\.\S*)\s+'
  r'(?P<year>\S+)\s+(?P<day>\S+)\s+'
  r'(?:\S+\s+){4}'
  r'(?P<begin>\S+)\s+(?P<end>\S+)'
)
dst_format = '{station}.IR.{component}.{year}.{day}.{begin}.{end}.sac'

for i, line in enumerate(sys.stdin, 1):
  m = src_pattern.match(line)
  if m:
    try:
      os.rename(m.group('current'), dst_format.format_map(m.groupdict()))
    except OSError as ex:
      print(ex, file=sys.stderr)
  else:
    print(
      'Non-matching source line {:d}: {!r}'.format(i, line.rstrip('\r\n')),
      file=sys.stderr)
```

Usage:

```sh
python3 rename.py < file-name-data.txt
```

Comment: your answer with python worked perfectly for me. Regards

Comment: I also need to multiply the last two column which are `(begin time)` and `(end time)` by 1000 inside the text file before renaming, is there any way to do that?

Comment: @NimaDolatabadi: Could you please open a [new question](/questions/ask) if you have a new or follow-up question? The comment section is not suitable or meant for new questions or extended discussion. You’re welcome to send me a comment with a notification to draw my attention to it. Thanks.

Comment: thanks sir. I will open another question and I have clicked on check mark you said earlier. Regards

Answer (score 0):

There is a command line tool, multiple move. It lets you move (which is also rename), copy, etc., based on patterns. Install it with

```
sudo apt install mmv
```

in a terminal window. Then run "man mmv" to see the manual page, or look here:
https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-mmv/

It can be a bit daunting because the problem is not simple. **Always** test on a copy of your data first.

There is also a graphical tool, filebot. It is written in Java and runs on Ubuntu. Simply search for it in the Ubuntu Software store or install with

```
sudo apt install filebot
```

Its main target is bulk renaming of video and music files and it can use database information from MusicBrainz and so on, but if I remember correctly (but check it out yourself please because I didn't sleep much this weekend :) ) also works well for non-media file sets. Their website is here:
https://www.filebot.net/

Comment: Those are useful tools! Please add usage examples to showcase how the OP could achieve the stated goal with them.